# React Native Webview handle url change listener

Tags: react-native

it is possible to handle URL change on React Native web view.

I try to handle with `onNavigationStateChange` listener. But it only once time firing. When the page is load firing onNavigationStateChange. And when I navigate to another page, this event not firing.

Any idea?

Comment: onNavigationStateChange fires for me each time when I change the url in the webview to a different domain, e.g. facebook.com to bbc.com. From testing it doesn't seem to fire for page changes within the same domain. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi thank you for feedback.
 i need for same domain. for example http://example.com/login to http://example.com/logout.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you but something like this may help you https://productpains.com/post/react-native/bridge-for-webview-and-react-native

Comment: There is a package already on npm but its on hold until it becomes part of core react native. You might be able to use it to allow two way communication between the native WebView and react native https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge

Answer (score 10):

With the reference to `import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'` you may be using old version of webview please try updating or try following `code/method` to get current navigation `path/url`.

In your case `onNavigationStateChange` is not returning navigated path so you can try using `onLoadProgress` which return every change in url.

**Instead of this**

```
 onNavigationStateChange={(state) => {
  console.log("current_path",path);

 }}
```

**try this**

This may get called multiple time please handle your condition accordingly.

```
 onLoadProgress={({ path}) => {
 console.log("current_path",path);
 }}
```

> This is how my WebView looks like

```
  <WebView
    source={{ uri: this.state.url }}
    onLoadEnd={() => this.hideSpinner()}
    onMessage={onMessage.bind(this)}
    ref={WEBVIEW_REF => (this.WebViewRef = WEBVIEW_REF)}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    onLoadProgress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
       //your code goes here       
    }}
    onNavigationStateChange={(state) => {
       //your code goes here       
    }} 
   />
```

Comment: I also changed to use onLoadProgress from using onNavigationStateChange.
onLoadProgress is being called always for any change when it starts and end in my SPA app.
You can get the same state change data from event.nativeEvent

Comment: Observe change in url by maintaining state locally in variable

Comment: Hi, i am using a webview to render a payment gateway html, i tried your solution and i keep getting path as undefined

Comment: @kd12345 have you checked with both function `onNavigationStateChange ` and `onLoadProgress ` either should return value or check the `gateway` returns change in url. there way to `inject script` in webview you can try with that

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your React Native (and React) version.
It should be fixed. Maybe was an old issue, because right now it's working OK.

Check this link: [React Native webview get url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099444/react-native-webview-get-url)

Answer (score 0):

I load website link in react native WebView and its has button when i click that it navigate to default mobile browser.

Running application in react native android Current scenario: when i click button in website its navigate to default browser and am not getting the url i tried above suggestions.

Expected scenario: When i click that button in website it should not navigate to default browser and i want that url which is opened in default browser.

```
my react version: "react-native": "0.64.0",

onLoadProgress = {({ nativeEvent }) => {
    //your code goes here       
}}
onNavigationStateChange={navState => {
    console.log("navState ", navState);
}}
```

Comment: Next time [edit] the answer to add the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onNavigationStateChange={({ url, canGoBack }) => {
          console.log("url>>>>>>>>",url);
        }}
```