# React Native webview get url

Tags: webview, react-native

Webview component allowing me to specify a destination url, e.g. facebook.com

```
render() {

    return (
        <WebView
          source={{uri: https://www.facebook.com}}
          style={{marginTop: 20}}
        />
    );
  }
```

However, If i click the link in facebook, how can I get the url being clicked or the url being landed?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here is a Webview I used for my previous project.

```
<WebView
       ref="webview"
       source={{uri:this.state.url}}
       onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
       javaScriptEnabled = {true}
       domStorageEnabled = {true}
       injectedJavaScript = {this.state.cookie}
       startInLoadingState={false}
     />
```

for you essential is this line:

```
           onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
```

and you can read the URL like this:

```
_onNavigationStateChange(webViewState){
  console.log(webViewState.url)
}
```

If I remember correctly this fires 3 times when loading a url.

webviewState object prototype:

```
{
  canGoBack: bool,
  canGoForward: bool,
  loading: bool,
  target: number,
  title: string,
  url: string,
}
```

The 3rd (final) time this event is called, the loading attribute is false

let me know if it helps.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Is there any explanation on webViewState detail ?

Comment: How to detect only url/hash change ? if the site does not change state, onNavigationStateChange does not trigger.

Comment: @chetan wouldn't the source change then? I haven't worked with RN in a long time

Comment: @dv3 : i tried with your code but it is not working in Android device

Comment: @dv3 this is saying me that can not read property 'url' of null.

Comment: I have put an work around with `onLoadProgress`

Comment: @Sagar ok nice!

Comment: @Sagar Nice idea!