# WebView - go to original URL

Tags: react-native, webview

The application I'm working on has one section where a `WebView` component (a **react-native** one) is loaded. Well, this `WebView` is loaded when the users taps an icon from the bottom navigation bar (sharing those details to make you understand the context better). The user can navigate inside that `WebView` and let's say that he arrives to a page that seems to be a **404** page. By tapping again that icon, the user would expect to load again the first URL loaded and he can get rid of that error page, but no, there's no method `goToTheFirst()` URL from a `WebView`. There's `goBack()` or `goForward()` methods but this doesn't help (maybe the user navigated through 10 different URL's to arrive to that **404** page).

I've tried this:

1. Update the already rendered source of the `WebView` by injecting a script (nothing happens).
2. Reload the `WebView` (reloading the web view it will reload the current URL where the user arrived by navigating into that `WebView`).

Does anybody have any idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this to retrieve the url of the current page: [React Native webview get url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099444/react-native-webview-get-url?rq=1)

Essentially:

1. Set a state that changes only once when you go from a regular component to a webview. That state variable will be the first url.
2. Inject Javascript, but instead of changing the rendered source, just make your script go to the page itself from the saved state. Look at the code inside `goBack()` and `goForward()` for reference.

Comment: Thank you for response! I don't need to get the current URL. And the original URL is known. To be more clear, I was asking how can you update the already rendered WebView component with a custom URL.