# React-native Webview history

Tags: react-native

I need web site addresses that some user have visited previously in webview.

```
<WebView
//Enable Javascript support
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
//For the Cache
    domStorageEnabled={true}
//View to show while loading the webpage
    renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
//Want to show the view or not
    startInLoadingState={true}
    ref={component => this.webview = component}
    source={{uri:  this.state.addr}}
    style={{flex:1}} 
/>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39099906/8434189)