# onNavigationStateChange not working in Android React Native

Tags: android, react-native, custom-scheme-url

Hello friends i want to integrate deep link in my react native project with Android so below is my code

```
 <WebView
source={{ uri: this.state.authURL }}
ref="webViewAndroidSample"
renderError={(error) => alert(error)}
startInLoadingState = {false}
javaScriptEnabled = {true}
domStorageEnabled = {true}
onNavigationStateChange = {this._onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}/> 

_onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(e){
    console.log("URL "+e.url);

}
```

When i click other link inside my webview i am not getting clicked link url in e.url which i log any idea how can i solve this issue?

Comment: What kind of a website do you load in your web view? If it is a single page application then the navigationStateChange event will not be triggered for the internal links.

Comment: @needsleep I used this url for webview [website](http://sc.test.clane.com/webview_test.html) In this url i have multiple link inside that, i want seprate href link all these two link on click webview in onNavigationStateChange , is it possible in android?

Comment: You can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66439365/2869767 because i was having same issue

Comment: I found a solution using onLoadProgress.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72555083/16607002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment I understand that you want to have a WebView in your react native app and inside there to load url with some links that open custom urls and that will trigger other actions inside the same app.

I don't know if there is an easy way to open a deep link from inside a WebView but you could try a different approach. You can use the onMessage method of the WebView and the window.postMessage to send messages from the webpage to your app like shown in this expo snack

https://snack.expo.io/HJSTrfA2f

Note the onMessage method. There you can insert your app's logic based on the message you get from the web view

```
onMessage={event => {
      alert('MESSAGE >>>>' + event.nativeEvent.data);
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

onLoadProgress:
Function that is invoked when the WebView is loading.

```html
 onLoadProgress={({ e }) => {
    console.log("URL ", e.nativeEvent.url);
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `onLoadProgress` function is what you should implement. As it has the very simillar parameters with `onNavigationStateChange`, like `url`, `canGoBack`, `title`, etc.

Update `react-native-webview` to the latest version.