# React Native Webview "onNavigationStateChange" returning empty document.title only on iOS device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, android-webview, react-native-webview

I'm trying to create a payment checkout process with Paypal, and using WebView to handle the request on an ExpressJS backend. The React Native app reads the document.title of the rendered html in the backend to determine the success or failure of a transaction. On Android it works perfectcly, however on iOS the document.title is always returned as "".

REACT NATIVE SECTION:

```
const INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT =
    `document.getElementById('total').value="${total}"; 
    document.getElementById('address').value="${address}"; 
    document.getElementById('firstName').value="${userProfile.firstName}";
    document.getElementById('lastName').value="${userProfile.lastName}";
    document.getElementById('email').value="${accessStore.auth.userEmail}";
    document.getElementById('addressDetails').value="${moreDetails}";
    setTimeout(function() {document.f1.submit()}, 1000);`
    
    
<WebView
     source={{uri: process.env.BACKEND_NODE_URL_PAYMENT}}
     onNavigationStateChange={(data) => {
         handleResponse(data), console.log(data)
     }}
     onMessage={(event) => {}}
     injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT}
/>
```

EXPRESS SECTION

```
app.get('/success', (req, res) => {

    var PayerID = req.query.PayerID;

    var execute_payment_json = {
         "payer_id": PayerID,
    };

    var paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

    paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment)
    {
         if (error) {
              console.log(error.response);
              throw error;
         } else {
             res.render('success');
         }
    });
});
```

RENDERED HTML IN EXPRESS JS

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>success</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Zahlung erfolgreich!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you may also need a ref, as per this GitHub issue comment: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1779#issuecomment-916809253

Comment: I tried adding that but still not working :(

Comment: This might be a bug. It used to work but I'm having the same issue now. Tested with react-native-webview 11.15 and 11.17. I don't know which version worked. Could even be iOS 15 that introduced the issue.

Comment: Yeah, honestly there's no concrete solution out there. I managed to solve it in the end by using a .includes() and the URL value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with a different approach in the end. I used the "url" value and used it in the conditional as

```
 if (data.url.includes('https://example.com/success')) {
     ///do if payment successfull
 }
 
 if (data.url.includes('https://example.com/cencel')) {
     ///do if payment is cancelled
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

I used the `onLoadProgress` property of web view to get URL through `e.nativeEvent`:

```
 onLoadProgress = {e => {
      let {url} = e?.nativeEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read in the WebView docs, in order to pass messages from Web to React Native you'll have to use `postMessage` in JavaScript and teh `onMessage` prop in React Native: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native

This means in theory your code should not have worked even on Android, so you definitely have an interesting use case!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same in one of my recent apps where html is handled from backend in react-native,
 pardon its not webview

i used `react-native-render-html` package to render the html collected from backend

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html';

const ComponentHTML = ({body}) => {
 // body is the props sent down from parent as response of - api call
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const source_ = {html: `${body}`};
return (
   <View style={styles.announceMentView}>
    <RenderHtml
      contentWidth={width}
      source={source_}
   />
  </View>
 )
}
export default ComponentHTML
```